# can't find cbQosCMPostPolicyBitRate64 oid for cisco

Tags: cisco, qos, snmp

i have use snmpwalk go get police Bit Rate Traffic policy-map(QOS) for my cisco ASR1006
but i need a 64bit barbecue my traffic is more of 5000Mbps
so 32bit can't handle it  .

```
~# snmpwalk -v2c -c aaa X.X.X.X 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.1.672.65536 = Counter32: 140
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.1.672.131072 = Counter32: 124
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.1.672.196608 = Counter32: 149
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.2.672.65536 = Counter32: 565783635
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.2.672.131072 = Counter32: 2787016045
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.2.672.196608 = Counter32: 1685627951
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.3.672.65536 = Counter64: 601861205075
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.3.672.131072 = Counter64: 535362960749
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.3.672.196608 = Counter64: 641635755055
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.4.672.65536 = Counter32: 196388
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.4.672.131072 = Counter32: 159292
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.4.672.196608 = Counter32: 147904
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.5.672.65536 = Counter32: 2518256453
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.5.672.131072 = Counter32: 425490298
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.5.672.196608 = Counter32: 1357191639
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.6.672.65536 = Counter64: 843482555583301
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.6.672.131072 = Counter64: 684154356004730
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.6.672.196608 = Counter64: 635244200139223
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.7.672.65536 = Gauge32: 3140898704
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.7.672.131072 = Gauge32: 534974704
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.7.672.196608 = Gauge32: 830404704
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.8.672.65536 = Counter32: 196388
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.8.672.131072 = Counter32: 159292
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.8.672.196608 = Counter32: 147904
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.9.672.65536 = Counter32: 2518256453
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.9.672.131072 = Counter32: 425490298
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.9.672.196608 = Counter32: 1357191639
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.10.672.65536 = Counter64: 843482555583301
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.10.672.131072 = Counter64: 684154356004730
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.10.672.196608 = Counter64: 635244200139223
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.11.672.65536 = Gauge32: 3140898704
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.11.672.131072 = Gauge32: 534974704 
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.11.672.196608 = Gauge32: 830404704  (this bitrate but only 32bit)
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.12.672.65536 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.12.672.131072 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.12.672.196608 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.13.672.65536 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.13.672.131072 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.13.672.196608 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.14.672.65536 = Counter64: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.14.672.131072 = Counter64: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.14.672.196608 = Counter64: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.15.672.65536 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.15.672.131072 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.15.672.196608 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.16.672.65536 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.16.672.131072 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.16.672.196608 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.17.672.65536 = Counter64: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.17.672.131072 = Counter64: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.17.672.196608 = Counter64: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.18.672.65536 = Gauge32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.18.672.131072 = Gauge32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.18.672.196608 = Gauge32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.19.672.65536 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.19.672.131072 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.19.672.196608 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.20.672.65536 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.20.672.131072 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.20.672.196608 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.21.672.65536 = Counter64: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.21.672.131072 = Counter64: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.21.672.196608 = Counter64: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.22.672.65536 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.22.672.131072 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.22.672.196608 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.23.672.65536 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.23.672.131072 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.23.672.196608 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.24.672.65536 = Counter64: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.24.672.131072 = Counter64: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.24.672.196608 = Counter64: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.25.672.65536 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.25.672.131072 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.25.672.196608 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.26.672.65536 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.26.672.131072 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.26.672.196608 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.27.672.65536 = Counter64: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.27.672.131072 = Counter64: 0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.27.672.196608 = Counter64: 0
```

i can't find oid for 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.29

http://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.29

Comment: It's possible it doesn't support it.

Comment: so how prtg can get a right counter ?